# PHP echo combination of HTML and function

Tags: php, ajax

When updating the prices in my Woocommerce cart, I am seeing an odd behaviour that is resulting in my HTML being stripped when entered as a single line after echoing.

For example, the following outputs only the HTML generated by the `wc_cart_totals_order_total_html()` function, i.e strips my `<td>` tags.

```
echo '<td>' . wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() . '</td>';

Result: £1.00
```

However, if echoed as separate lines, all works as expected. Is this an expected behaviour and if so is it possible to update my single line method to work?

```
echo '<td>';
echo wc_cart_totals_order_total_html();
echo '</td>';

Result: <td>£1.00</td>
```

Comment: Could it be because you missed out the class attributes from the one that does not work?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was supposed to remove these. That is not the issue

Comment: Assuming you have a `<?php` before the echo the result should be the same

Comment: `Result: <td>£1.00</td>` That makes no sense, in a table put the `Result:` inside the `<td></td>`

Comment: It sounds like to me that `wc_cart_totals_order_total_html()` does not `return` the actual html, but rather does an `echo` inside itself?

Comment: @IncredibleHat - possibly - if that is the case then assume nothing I can do?

Comment: If my lookup of that is correct, it is doing this inside itself: `echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', $value );` ... which is kind of annoying for a function to do. Especially when they say to use it like: `$result = wc_cart_totals_order_total_html();` .. like, uhhh, I see no `return` in that [function definition](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_cart_totals_order_total_html/).

Comment: So anyhow, doing `echo '<td>' . wc_cart_totals_order_total_html() . '</td>';` means that the function echo's its crap out before that `echo` is finished, so you end up with an empty `<td></td>` after the value echo'd out by the function. Inspecting your raw html output you would see this oddity as well. So yes, you have to echo out the begin `<td>` first, then call the function, then echo out the end `</td>` to make it do valid html.

Comment: Can you switch it arround? This is how WooCommerce do it in their "review-order.php" template file: `<td><?php wc_cart_totals_order_total_html(); ?></td>`. If you can't switch it around then you are probably better off adding a function to hook into the `woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html` filter and modify the html to your needs before it is echo'd by that function.